# python import from the sub-directories

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following directories:

```
|-- project
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- proj1
|   |   |-- file.py
|   |   |-- file.py~
|   |   `-- __init__.py
|   `-- proj2
|       |-- call.py
|       |-- call.py~
|       `-- __init__.py
```

And the call.py has:

```
from proj1.file import hello

hello('nishant')
```

And the file.py has.

```
def hello(arg):
    print 'hello ,' + arg
```

When i am trying to call outside the project directory
`python project/proj2/call.py` i get the import Error: No module named proj1.file

Any Idea ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the `call.py` and `file.py` are not in same path so you need too add the `prog1` to path of `call.py` with `..`:

```
import sys ,os
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
if not path in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(1, path)
del path
```

Comment: Your method is correct, but is there not any other method instead of adding these fourlines ..? can from __future__ import absolute_import be useful in this situation ..?

Comment: im not familiar with `absolute_import` , you can try it by yourself , so why you want to use lees code ?

Comment: Less code, I just that previous we use .. to go to the directories in the situtation like these ... thats why i was looking for something to avoid the excess of code ..

Comment: mmm, its the way for your problem , if you dont want use this at all put them in a same directory or you can , dont use `if` ! i have not any idea here !

Answer (score 0):

This is because imports are relative to paths in your PATH environment variable (or `sys.path` in python). By default this var only contains the current directory, which is the directory you run from.

Run you project from within the `project` directory: `python proj2/call.py`

Alternatively, you can append your project root to `sys.path` before doing the imports:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT)
```

Comment: If, I call it within the project directory then again i am getting: ImportError: No module named proj1.file